# ExecutorService might execute on calling thread?

Tags: java, android

If you read the documentation for [Executor.execute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable)), it says:

> The command may execute in a new thread, in a pooled thread, or **in the
>   calling thread**, at the discretion of the Executor implementation.

My understanding is that, by *calling thread*, they mean the thread that calls the `execute` command.

This has never happened in my experience, so my question is: Does this really ever happen?

Since the calling Thread controls the UI, I cannot allow additional work on the calling Thread. I am particularly concerned about whether this could happen when I construct the `ExecutorService` using the `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads)` method.

Comment: the documentation says that it depends on the Executor's implementation. You could implement your own executor which just call `Runnable.run()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ExecutorService` is an interface which defines a broad contract. If you look at implementations, say [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) for example, you will have more precise characteristics:

> An ExecutorService that executes each submitted task using one of possibly several pooled threads, normally configured using Executors factory methods.

Note that the javadoc linked above details the fact that the `ExecutorService`s returned by the various `Executors` factory methods are `ThreadPoolExecutor`s.

So to answer your question more directly: **`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads)` will not execute tasks on the calling thread.**

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, this quote from the [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) javadoc provides an example of an `Executor` implementation which runs the code in the calling thread,

> However, the Executor interface does not strictly require that execution be asynchronous. In the simplest case, an executor can run the submitted task immediately in the caller's thread:

```
class DirectExecutor implements Executor {    
    public void execute(Runnable r) {
        r.run();    
    }  
}
```

> More typically, tasks are executed in some thread other than the caller's thread. The executor below spawns a new thread for each task.

```
class ThreadPerTaskExecutor implements Executor {    
    public void execute(Runnable r) {
        new Thread(r).start();    
    }  
}
```